# how to pass 3D array to a 3D chart in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

```
$(function() {
    myChart3 = new Highcharts.Chart({...});
    })

function Show3DScatter(str) {       
        factor01 = document.getElementById("ThreeD_factor01").value;
        factor02 = document.getElementById("ThreeD_factor02").value;
        factor03 = document.getElementById("ThreeD_factor03").value;
        $.get('ajax.php').done(function(data) { 

                data03 = JSON.parse(data); 
                // prepare data
                for ( var key in data03) {

                    var x = 'data03[' + key + '].' + factor01 + ';';
                    var y = 'data03[' + key + '].' + factor02 + ';';
                    var z = 'data03[' + key + '].' + factor03 + ';';
                    arr.push([ eval(x), eval(y), eval(z) ]);
                }
                for ( var key in arr) {

                    arr_3D.push(arr[key]);
                }

            // add data
            myChart3.series[0].update({
                data : arr_3D
            });

    }
```

**as you can see above, it did not work all the time, annoying so much, why it cannot get data from arr_3D??? plz help. THANKS.** **(I do not copy my code in detail for convenience, the issue is the code**

```
myChart3.series[0].update({
                data : arr_3D
            });
```

**did not work.)**

Comment: have you tried to console log your arr_3D? what is the result of this console.log? Do you have any errors in your console (Developer tools)?

Comment: Hi I tried console.log, and it gave me this: [Array[3], Array[3], Array[3], Array[3]], looks right..., I did not get the points shown in the chart..

Comment: @Grzegorz, Hi thanks I tried console.log, and it gave me this in detail:<!-- [Array[3], Array[3], Array[3], Array[3]]
0
:
Array[3]
0
:
"46"
1
:
"179"
2
:
"46"
length
:
3
__proto__
:
Array[0]
1
:
Array[3]
0
:
"31"
1
:
"178"
2
:
"31"
length
:
3
__proto__
:
Array[0]
2
:
Array[3]
0
:
"45"
1
:
"178"
2
:
"45"
length
:
3
__proto__
:
Array[0]
3
:
Array[3]
0
:
"56"
1
:
"167"
2
:
"56"
length
:
3
__proto__
:
Array[0]
length
:
4
__proto__
:
Array[0] -->

Comment: @Grzegorz, and I tried this, myChart3.series[0].addPoint(arr_3D[1]); no data shown in chart, but if I replaced it this way  myChart3.series[0].addPoint([46, 56, 67]); I got the point in the chart...

Comment: @Grzegorz, Hi, I just now filtered my value with this function parseFloat(), then I got my points in the chart~!! so strange, why?

Comment: It is because you were using string instead of numbers in your y and z values. Highcharts expects your y and z values to be a numbers so it can calculate extremes etc.

Comment: Well, yes, in the beginning it is string format in the JSON data.. Thanks